# Freemarker missing spring message

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, internationalization, freemarker

I am loading asynchronously (Ajax call to Spring MVC Controller) a free marker template. But i get error message complaining about missing message property.

> This is my Spring controller method

```
@RequestMapping('/messages/{messageId}')
public String conversation(@PathVariable('messageId') Long messageId, ModelMap model) {
    //BUILD CONVERSATION MODEL model.put....

    "async/conversation"
}
```

> async/conversation.ftl

```
.....<@spring.message "user.conversation.title"/>.....
```

I have message properties with

```
user.conversation.title Conversation
```

This message is working just fine in other scenario, i think there is some issue loading the template asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: I had forgotten to make an import.

```
<#import "/spring.ftl" as spring/>
```